# Random Graph with networkx package: how to make the program faster

Tags: python, performance, graph, networkx

I want to build a graph that is a grid of size 2N+1 times 2N+1, with each edge being present with probability $p$.

Here's my code.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np


def getGrid(N):
    G=nx.grid_2d_graph(2*N+1,2*N+1)
    return G





def getGridBond(N,p):
    G = getGrid(N)
    for elt in list(G.edges):
        pt_1 = elt[0]
        pt_2 = elt[1]
        if np.random.binomial(1,p) == 0:
            G.remove_edge(pt_1,pt_2)
    return G

for i in tqdm(range(0,100)):
    getGridBond(100,0.5)
```

This code takes a long time, with each iteration taking about 1.7s.

How can I make it faster?

Thank you.

Comment: why are you repeating the same thing 100 times?

Comment: @dankal444 - each iteration repeats the same steps, but generates a different graph.  So this generates 100 random graphs that are each generated by the same process.  The 100 graphs will not be the same graph.

Comment: @Joel `getGrid` is repeated non-necessarily, its better to cache it and re-use it (for example using deepcopy)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here with the randomized steps.  Here's your code:

```
def getGridBond(N,p):
     G = getGrid(N)
     for elt in list(G.edges):
         pt_1 = elt[0]
         pt_2 = elt[1]
         if np.random.binomial(1,p) == 0:
             G.remove_edge(pt_1,pt_2)
     return G
```

First, you don't need to define `pt_1` and `pt_2` and then remove the edge.  Instead, you could remove the edge with `G.remove_edge(*elt)`.  However, we can do better.  You should work under the assumption that each random number generation is expensive.  When you're working with random numbers where sometimes something happens and sometimes something doesn't, there are often ways to turn the calculation into one or two random number generations which you can use to find all the "true" cases.

You could slightly speed up your `if np.random.binomial(1,p)==0` call to `if np.random.random()<p` (assuming my understanding of `p` is correct).

However, we can do better: instead of doing this, `np.random.binomial(len(G.edges),` 1-p)`gives a number from the correct distribution for how many edges to delete.  Then choose this number of edges, with`np.random.choice(list(G.edges),...)` (without replacement).

So

```
def getGridBond(N,p):
     G = getGrid(N)
     edgelist = list(G.edges)
     delete_count = np.random.binomial(len(edges), 1-p)
     delete_edges = np.random.choice(edgelist, size = delete_count, replace=False)
     G.remove_edges_from(delete_edges)
     return G
```

should be faster.

Comment: There is another way that I can speed this up, but I think this one is better.  Let me know if this isn't enough for you and I may be able to do better.

Comment: As always, you should check that the answers given are reasonable.  I haven't checked this for bugs as closely as I would check code for myself.

Answer (score 0):

I took Joel answer, resolved errors, added caching and some other improvements. It turned out to be ~2.5x faster (disregarding first run, before cache makes a difference).

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pickle
from functools import lru_cache
from tqdm import tqdm


@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def getGrid2(N):
    G=nx.grid_2d_graph(2*N+1,2*N+1)
    return G

def getGridBond2(N, p):
    G = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(getGrid2(N)))
    edgelist = [edge for edge in G.edges()]
    n_endges = len(edgelist)
    delete_count = np.random.binomial(n_endges, 1 - p)
    to_remove_indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(n_endges), size=delete_count, replace=False)
    delete_edges = [edgelist[idx] for idx in to_remove_indices]
    G.remove_edges_from(delete_edges)
    return G
```

my current profiling results

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    42                                           @do_profile(follow=[getGridBond, getGridBond2])
    43                                           def main():
    44         1    3038673.0 3038673.0      6.3      getGridBond(100,0.5)
    45         1    2510231.0 2510231.0      5.2      getGridBond2(100,0.5)
    46        11      25183.0   2289.4      0.1      for i in tqdm(range(0,10)):
    47        10   30320885.0 3032088.5     63.2          getGridBond(100,0.5)
    48        10   12092567.0 1209256.7     25.2          getGridBond2(100,0.5)
```

Comment: I think this code keeps removing same edge from G no?

Comment: @Phil yes, sorry, fixed this problem but this decreased speed-up gain by much. Still, 2.5x faster than baseline method